# Attaching a cookie to a view in Symfony2

Tags: cookies, http-headers, symfony

I've found a few questions and pages dealing with cookies in Symfony2 but there doesn't seem to be any clear consensus on exactly how this is supposed to work.  I can, of course, just fall back to using PHP's native `setcookie` function but I feel that it should be an easy thing to do with Symfony2 as well.

I have an action in my controller from which I simply want to return a view with a cookie attached.  Thus far I have seem examples basically like this:

```
use Symfony\Compentnt\HttpFoundation\Response;

public function indexAction() {
  $response = new Response();
  $response->headers->setCookie(new Cookie('name', 'value', 0, '/');
  $response->send();
}
```

The problem with this is that it sends the response... and doesn't render the view.  If I set the cookie without sending the headers the view is rendered but the header (cookie) is not sent.

Poking around I found the `sendHeaders()` method in the Response object so I'm now manually calling that in my action before returning and that seems to work:

```
public function indexAction() {
  ...
  $response->sendHeaders();
  return array('variables' => 'values');
}
```

But is this really the expected pattern to use?  In previous versions of symfony I could set the headers in my controller and expect the view controller to handle sending whatever I had sent.  It seems now that I must manually send them from the action to get it to work, meaning I have to call this from any action that I set headers in.  Is this the case or is there something that I'm missing that's so obvious that no one has bothered to even mention it in any of the documentation?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I think you're on the right lines with:

```
$response->headers->setCookie(new Cookie('name', 'value', 0, '/'));
```

If you're trying to render a template then check out the docs here:

[Symfony2 Templating Service](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/templating.html#configuring-and-using-the-templating-service)

If you look at the line:

```
return $this->render('AcmeArticleBundle:Article:index.html.twig');
```

basically the render method is returning a response (which the controller then returns) which has the content of the twig template, all you have to do is intercept this:

```
$response = $this->render('AcmeArticleBundle:Article:index.html.twig');
$response->headers->setCookie(new Cookie('name', 'value', 0, '/'));
return $response;
```

I think that's it anyway...

Comment: Still trying to get my bearings with Symfony2.  I've used similar code with Zend framework, explicitly calling the template from within the controller.  I guess I'm just confused as to why by default the view is called but if i try to modify the response it isn't. Thanks!

Comment: Are you using the annotation `Template` on the Action? If so then the empty version of that annotation renders the template with the same name as the action. If you manually return another response I think it might overwrite the `Template` annotation in which case you don't get the view content. I'm not sure this is exactly right but imagine the annotation like a wrapper around the action that does `if ( !($controllerReturn instaceof Response) ) { // render template } else { return $controllerReturn; }`.

Comment: To follow up my last explanation you can check out `Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\EventListener\TemplateListener` specifically the `onKernelView` method, you can see how it takes the controller's return (`$parameters`) and either uses them to generate a template or returns them directly. That's digging a bit too much into things though, I only post it because you seemed to want an explanation and sometimes those are like an annoying itch ;).

Comment: Very much so.  Thanks much for your help.  Symfony2 is definitely a different beast than its previous incarnation so it's going to take me some time to figure out all of its arcane inner workings such as this!

Comment: Almost 7 years later, I might be late to the party, but when using it in a rendered action like this ```{{ render( controller("AppBundle:SomeControllerName:someActionName" )) }}```, the cookies are not sent unless you explicitly use ```$response->sendHeaders()```

Comment: @MaxDamage 7 years later or not, you just saved me a LOT of searching for the problem :)