# Symfony 4 remove cookies

Tags: symfony

I have a cookie setup code.

```
public function checkInviter(int $inviter)
{        
   $response = new RedirectResponse($this->generateUrl('app_homepage'));
   if ($inviter > 0) {
        $response->headers->setCookie(Cookie::create('_inviter_id', $inviter, new \DateTime("+ 30  days")));
        $response->sendHeaders();
    }

    return $response;
```

}

Further in the registration I want to delete / clear it. If I create a new response, then he does not know about the cookies set.
How to work with cookies?

```
public function register() {
    $response = new Response();
    dump($response); // cleared Response
    $response->headers->removeCookie('_inviter_id', '/', null);
    $response->send();

    return $this->render('security/register.html.twig');
}
```

I found some [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7923382/6538632), but it is not entirely accurate.

Comment: What do you mean by "How to work with cookies?" - what exactly is not working with the given code?

Comment: I wrote that when you delete, the response is empty, the cookie does not delete.

Comment: Have you tried to use the other answer? I don't think that the given code uses your handcrafted `$response` after all, because `$this->render` does not know anything about it

Comment: $response->send(); talks about it before

Comment: Are you sure? `$response` is a new instance of a response, and you should assign it to the function call of `$this->render` if you want to use it

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are duplicating the generation of responses: there are technically two different responses sent out, as you generate one in your controller and Symfony creates a second one during `$this->render`.

You should reuse your own Response object by setting it as the third parameter of `render` to avoid problems. The full code might look as following (reusing the method `clearCookie` which you've already found):

```
public function register() {
    $response = new Response();
    $response->headers->clearCookie('_inviter_id', '/', null);

    return $this->render('security/register.html.twig', [], $response);
}
```

Comment: Thank. I will mark your answer. But my option also works even without `render(...$response)`

Comment: Yes, it does, as the proper headers are sent. But it might have side effects, which you should avoid

Answer (score 0):

Testing the code, I found a solution. Use

```
$response->headers->clearCookie('_inviter_id');
```

This clears the value and sets a new expiration date.